# How to execute a task after a project is built

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

After, my project is build I'd like to execute a task. I need to read and modify files after a project is built. I usually code in visual studio and it has MSBuild that can accomplish this.

Basically, the task will read the application.properties file and other properties files. Based on whats in the files I will build a `Dockerfile`. Is there a way to accomplish this in intellij?

Comment: I know how to do it with sbt (scala build tool). If you use maven I think you need to write your own plugin or use already existing one. Search for "maven custom tasks"  if you use maven.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA can run Maven/Ant/Gradle tasks on certain events (like after compilation). You can wrap your task into a one of these build systems to run it automatically.

Comment: Are you using docker maven plugin?